# Which part of the token that would be used for SAML2 Assertion validation and What are the steps of validating the assertion?

Tags: validation, saml-2.0, pingfederate

I am very new to SAML and ping federate. Please explain me the steps to validate SAML2 assertion? If any specific language is to be used, please mention that also. The validation should be in the context of ping federate.

Thanks
Aswini

Comment: Your use case is not clear. Are you using PingFederate? Or are you trying to build something that needs to consume an assertion from PingFederate?

Comment: Yes, I am using Ping Federate. How to authorize SAML2 assertion against the attribute service? What are the steps to do? I also need to understand the steps to generate SAML2 assertion and consume the same. It is very ambiguous. It will be helpful if you could help me. Thanks

Comment: To generate an assertion you need an Idp (Identity Provider) implementation. There are many existing libraries for that. What programming language/platform/frameworks are you using?

Comment: Which is better to use? Open SAML or SpringSecurity SAML?

Comment: I found that SAML can be generated using Java libraries. I came across these libraries. I am confused if Open SAML and spring SAML are two different libraries. Is spring SAML using open SAML within it. If both are different libraries, which is better to generate SAML token? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't going to be the most kosher of answers, but you need to understand why you're doing before you can understand what you're doing. As such, I've compiled a list of the training videos that we host at Ping Identity. I would follow the order that I put them in - that way you learn some basics, and then learn some PingFed specifics.

- [Federation](https://ping.force.com/Support/PingIdentityVideoLibrary?id=1017466745001)
- [Federation Best Practices](https://ping.force.com/Support/PingIdentityVideoLibrary?id=900235458001)
- [SAML](https://ping.force.com/Support/PingIdentityVideoLibrary?id=2748494952001)
- [PingFederate Overview](https://ping.force.com/Support/PingIdentityVideoLibrary?id=1018696342001)
- [Create an HTML Adapter](https://ping.force.com/Support/PingIdentityVideoLibrary?id=1506510615001)
- [Creating a connection with PingFederate](https://ping.force.com/Support/PingIdentityVideoLibrary?id=1011570451001)

Comment: I could create IDP and SP connections. How to validate the SAML2.0 assertion? I prefer to use OpenSAML. Is there any code or steps for validation? Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: That's another question. Ask it as a new one, not a comment to a reply.